# Vuejs Custom Component - Two-Way-Binding not working, One-Way-Binding works

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm getting started with refactoring my application to use vue.js as front-end framework and began writing the first components i'll use.

For this i created a component for a table, and one for the rows.

One-Way-Binding works so far (as in my model changes and the changes will be reflected by updating the UI).

My model for this part is an Array of Objects, where i'm binding to multiple attributes, one is them is called **Checked**.

Now if i change the model, the view is updated, the checkbox will be checked, but if i check the checkbox manually, the model is not updated.

```
Vue.component('peak-table-row', {
    props: ["peak", "graphname", "idx"],
    data() {
        return {
            _peak: {}
        };
    },
    created() {
        console.log(this);
        this.$data._peak = getPeak(this.graphname, this.idx);
    },
    render(h) {
        return h('tr', {
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: getColor(this.idx, 0.5)
                }
            }, [
                h("td", [h("input", {attrs: {type:"checkbox",checked:this.peak.Checked}})]),
            ]
        );
    }
});
Vue.use("peak-table-row");
```

Until now the documentation was really helpful, but i can't seem to find how I'd resolve this.

Comment: Vue (like React) uses 1 way binding. You can use [.sync modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) to perform 2 way binding

Answer (score 1):

You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on form input like checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="_peak.Checked">
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nrvxm76n9l